# Remove rows from R dataset based on matching

Tags: r, row, matching

I did a word learning experiment with 54 participants. The design was such that each participant would be learning 12 cognate words and 12 non-cognate words. However, I had to remove some observations from the dataset, ending up with 1591 cognate observations and 1816 non-cognate observations.

Now, I want to calculate the correlation between scores for cognates and non-cognates. This means that I will have to reduce the 1816 non-cognate observations to 1591, because correlations are always performed with equal samples.

I could just remove rows 1592-1816, but that would not be ideal, because I would loose all non-cognates for the later participants (the data are sorted by participant number).

What I'd rather do, is loop through all the participants, and for each participant remove as many 'surplus' non-cognates so that the number of cognates and non-cognates becomes equal for that participant.

This is an example of the data for 2 participants (note that words are tested at multiple points in time, ideally this would also be taken into account when removing data):

```
structure(list(Participant = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "34", "35", "36", "37", 
"38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", 
"49", "50", "51", "52", "54", "55", "56", "57"), class = "factor"), 
    Word = structure(c(5L, 77L, 23L, 40L, 30L, 8L, 73L, 28L, 
    48L, 44L, 58L, 69L, 50L, 57L, 45L, 6L, 56L, 53L, 63L, 65L, 
    77L, 5L, 40L, 23L, 30L, 8L, 28L, 73L, 48L, 58L, 44L, 50L, 
    69L, 57L, 45L, 56L, 6L, 63L, 53L, 65L, 23L, 30L, 40L, 5L, 
    8L, 77L, 73L, 48L, 28L, 57L, 69L, 58L, 50L, 45L, 44L, 53L, 
    65L, 6L, 63L, 56L, 5L, 40L, 8L, 77L, 30L, 23L, 28L, 48L, 
    73L, 57L, 45L, 50L, 69L, 58L, 44L, 63L, 53L, 56L, 6L, 16L, 
    13L, 81L, 82L, 52L, 1L, 12L, 75L, 55L, 78L, 70L, 66L, 80L, 
    83L, 64L, 68L, 25L, 47L, 11L, 26L, 4L, 19L, 36L, 13L, 16L, 
    82L, 81L, 52L, 1L, 75L, 12L, 78L, 55L, 70L, 80L, 66L, 64L, 
    83L, 68L, 25L, 11L, 47L, 4L, 26L, 19L, 36L, 13L, 16L, 1L, 
    82L, 52L, 81L, 78L, 12L, 75L, 55L, 70L, 80L, 66L, 64L, 83L, 
    68L, 25L, 4L, 11L, 47L, 36L, 19L, 26L), .Label = c("aambeeld", 
    "bezem", "brandblusser", "broodrooster", "buis", "citruspers", 
    "dienblad", "dobber", "dweil", "emmer", "garde", "gesp", 
    "gieter", "gum", "heggenschaar", "hengel", "hes", "kaars", 
    "kapstok", "keppel", "kist", "klapper", "klos", "knikker", 
    "knuffel", "kooi", "kous", "kraag", "kroon", "kruiwagen", 
    "kruk", "kurk", "kussen", "kwast", "lantaarn", "lessenaar", 
    "mijter", "onderzetter", "pak", "passer", "peddel", "pet", 
    "pruik", "puntenslijper", "rammelaar", "reddingsvest", "rietje", 
    "rits", "romper", "sambabal", "schort", "schroef", "servet", 
    "skelter", "slab", "slang", "slinger", "speen", "speldje", 
    "spijker", "spuit", "staf", "stamper", "stelt", "stofzuiger", 
    "stokpaard", "stolp", "tamboerijn", "tol", "tooi", "toverstaf", 
    "tuinbroek", "tulband", "vergiet", "veter", "vijl", "vijzel", 
    "waaier", "wafelijzer", "wip", "zaag", "zeis", "zwemvleugel"
    ), class = "factor"), Cognate = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Cognate", 
    "Non-cognate"), class = "factor"), TestingMoment = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Main2", 
    "Main4", "Post", "FollowUp"), class = "factor"), Score = c(0, 
    1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0.71, 1, 1, 0.86, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 0.86, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0.43, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 0.86, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.75, 0, 0, 0, 0.57, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.45, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0.8, 
    1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0)), .Names = c("Participant", "Word", "Cognate", "TestingMoment", 
"Score"), row.names = c(97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 
104L, 105L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 
118L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 130L, 
133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 144L, 
145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 152L, 154L, 155L, 157L, 158L, 
159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 
171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 178L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 
185L, 186L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 
198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 
210L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 
221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 228L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 232L, 
233L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 243L, 
244L, 245L, 246L, 247L, 248L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 254L, 255L, 
256L, 257L, 258L, 259L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 264L), class = "data.frame")
```

What is the best way to go?

Comment: I didn't understand what non-cognates you want to remove.

Comment: Well, basically I'd want to keep the non-cognates that match the cognates in terms of participant number and testing moment. After that, it wouldn't matter so match which ones would be removed (perhaps I could keep the ones that best match the cognates in length, but for now that wouldn't be so important).

Comment: Isn't it possible that for some participants `number of cognates > number of non-cognates` ?

Comment: It could be possible, but if that would happen, it would be rare. Do you need me to check?

Comment: Well,  if it does happen and you only remove non-cognates, you will still  have an imbalance.  You probably should check.

Comment: True. So the question really extends to removing the rows such that the number of cognates and non-cognates becomes equal for each participant at each testing moment.

Comment: And you were right, because for 3 out of 54 participants, there are more cognates than non-cognates.

Comment: That makes it a little more complicated, but still doable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A somewhat smaller answer.

```
df2    = df     ## Preserve original data
for(Part in levels(df2$Participant)) {
    Tab    = table(df2$Cognate[df2$Participant == Part])
    if(Tab[1] == Tab[2]) { next }
    Big   = ifelse(Tab[1] > Tab[2], 1, 2)
    Small = ifelse(Tab[1] < Tab[2], 1, 2)

    Rem1   = sample(Tab[Big], Tab[Big] - Tab[Small])
    Remove = which(df2$Participant == Part &  df2$Cognate == levels(df2$Cognate)[Big])[Rem1]
    df2 = df2[-Remove,]
}
table(df2$Cognate)
```

Comment: Nice! In my code, I added a if to check if the amount of Cognates and Non-cognates were equal, but I added a `break` to it. Will it cause the for to brek to? This is why you have `next` ?

Comment: @TheBiro  `next` will go immediately to the next value in the `for` loop (participant) without executing the rest of the loop.  I think that your `break` might actually be an error. I think that `break` will completely stop the execution of the `for` loop and so not go on to later participants.Too bad we only have one participant to test with :-)

Comment: Just in case you're interested, I have added example data for two participants.

Comment: @Johanna Good addition with more Non-cognates. My code still works.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! I'm currently trying to extend your code to take into account the testing moment as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my answer, it's big and weird but it loops through each user, check if `Cognate` or `Non-cognate` is more frequent and remove until it gets equal (remember to assign your data to `data` variable):

```
final_data <- NULL
for (ptcp in unique(data$Participant)) {

  # subset to chose each participant
  new_data <- data[which(data$Participant==ptcp), ]

  # Check if Non-cognate and Cognate are equal
  if ( length(which(new_data$Cognate=="Non-cognate")) == length(which(new_data$Cognate=="Cognate")) ) break

  # Check if have more Non-cognate than Cognate
  if ( length(which(new_data$Cognate=="Non-cognate")) > length(which(new_data$Cognate=="Cognate")) ) {
    # Loop while they are not equal
    while (length(which(new_data$Cognate=="Non-cognate")) > length(which(new_data$Cognate=="Cognate"))) {

      # Removes the first row of "non-cognate
      id <- which(new_data$Cognate=="Non-cognate")
      new_data <- new_data[-id[1],]

    }

    # Check if have more Cognate than Non-cognate
  } else if ( length(which(new_data$Cognate=="Cognate")) > length(which(new_data$Cognate=="Non-cognate")) ) {
    # Loop while they are not equal
    while (length(which(new_data$Cognate=="Cognate")) > length(which(new_data$Cognate=="Non-cognate"))) {

      # Removes the first row of "non-cognate
      id <- which(new_data$Cognate=="Cognate")
      new_data <- new_data[-id[1],]

    }

  }

  # Combine each user to final_data
  final_data <- rbind(final_data, new_data)

}
```